# Using and replacing sequential elements of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Very simple question but I am an absolute beginner, so apologies if this has already been answered.

I need to pick sequential elements of a list, excluding t=1 and t=T, and use them in a function. For ht the list element in position t,

```
h:={h1,h2,h3,...hT}
hnew=f[t_]:=h[[t-1]]-h[[t+1]]
```

Then I want to update the existing value of $h_t$ by $h_{new}$, where $h_{new} = h_{t-1}-h_{t+1}$ and repeat until T-1 (second to last element).

Please note that I heed the definition `h:={}` because at the end of the process the updated vector will replace the original one (this is part of a bigger loop).

I have tried `ReplacePart` and a `Do` loop but I could not get them to work.

Again, I apologise for the format and if this question has already been asked.

Comment: Please provide your *Mathematica* in a copyable format. You can use the `{}` button in the editor for proper formating.

Comment: You might want to check [Understand the difference between Set (or =) and SetDelayed (or :=)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18487/18476).

Comment: What should the final output look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is to me a typical Mathematica solution.

```
f[{a_, b_}] := b
f[{b_, c_}] := b
f[{a_, b_, c_}] := a - c
Developer`PartitionMap[f, list, 3, 1, {-2, 2}, {}]
```

[`PartitionMap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Developer/ref/PartitionMap.html) is a combination of [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Partition.html) and [`Map (/@)`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html).

`Partition` is used to create sublists:

```
Partition[Range[5], 3, 1, {-2, 2}, {}]
(* Out: {{1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5}} *)
```

And mapping `f` onto this list gives us

```
f /@ {{1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5}}
(* Out: {f[{1, 2}], f[{1, 2, 3}], f[{2, 3, 4}], f[{3, 4, 5}], f[{4, 5}]} *)
```

So as you can see `f` now has all of the right data that it needs to compute the element at the position that it occupies in the list. We need to create a function that extracts this information and uses it appropriately. And this is the function that we've already seen:

```
f[{a_, b_}] := b
f[{b_, c_}] := b
f[{a_, b_, c_}] := a - c
```

Comment: Many thanks! That solved my problem and now I only have to deal with updating the list. Next time I will use a copyable format too. Any suggestions on how to update the list are more than welcome.

Comment: @titus What do you mean by "update the list"? ``list = Developer`PartitionMap[f,list,...]``?

Answer (score 2):

Using the undocumented 6-argument form of `Partition` where the sixth argument can be function:

```
foo = Subtract @@ ({##}[[{1, -1}]]) &;
Partition[Array[Subscript[h, #] &, {6}], 3, 1, None, {}, foo] // TeXForm
```

> $\left\{h_1 - h_3, h_2 - h_4, h_3 - h_5, h_4 - h_6\right\}$

Further examples:

```
Partition[Range[5], 3, 1, None, {}, foo]
```

> {-2, -2, -2}

```
Partition[RandomSample @ Range[5], 3, 1, None, {}, foo]
```

> {-3, -1, 4}